# PHP icon doesn't appear in IIS Manager

Tags: php, iis, iis-10

I have **PHP 5.6.40** running successfully on my Windows 10 / IIS 10. But the PHP icon doesn't appear in my IIS manager. This is a new workstation that I just set up and configured. On my old workstation, the PHP icon existed in my IIS / Windows 10 - but this time around I must have missed a step. All the online articles I can find about this (including stack posts) say to install PHP on IIS and go through all the steps I have already gone through. I don't want to redo an installation because:

1. I already have PHP working and don't want to break it.
2. I need this specific old version of PHP (5.6) so it matches my server.

What do I need to do so that my specific (already installed and working) version of PHP shows up in IIS manager so that I can manage PHP.ini and the various other settings?

Comment: So everything works except that you don't see a PHP icon in IIS? Does it really matter? Are you running PHP through IIS in production as well?

Comment: In production, my PHP is on linux. The PHP icon is handy in IIS - makes it easier to manage various things.

Comment: HTTP://phpmanager.xyz

Comment: Lex Li - perfect - please post that as the solution so I can accept it.